# Has anybody encountered filter not supported error in OroCRM?

Tags: orocrm

We recently started getting the following error

```
[
    {
        "title": "filter constraint",
        "detail": "The filter is not supported.",
        "source": "include"
    },
    {
        "title": "filter constraint",
        "detail": "The filter is not supported.",
        "source": "page[size]"
    }
]
```

This happens when trying to hit this URL

```
https://[redacted]/api/requirements?filter[opportunity]=123456&include=group,person&page[size]=-1
```

This is a legacy app that hasn't been touched or modified in months, and on Monday it was reported that this started happening with one of the basic features.

I'm at a loss at this point as to where I should be looking trying to fix this issue.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the client that uses an API doesn't send the `Accept: application/vnd.api+json` header that is required to use a new API with the above filters.

If the client hasn't changed, check the web server or any intermediate services for truncating headers.